# Trying to understand step in proof about minimizing ||Ax|| subject to ||x|| = 1

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, svd

Let $A$ = $UDV^T$, where $D$ is diagonal, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal.

We want to find the $x$ that minimizes ||$Ax$|| subject to ||$x$|| = 1.

1. Minimize ||$UDV^Tx$||.
2. ||$UDV^Tx$|| = ||$DV^tx$|| and ||$x$|| = $||V^tx$||.

And so forth ...

It's presented in the proof without proof, so it must be pretty simple. Yet, I'm having a hard time seeing how to show it.

Comment: Orthogonal matrices preserve the norm.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how that applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $U$ preserves the norm, it is the same to minimize $\|UDV^t x\|$ and to minimize $\|DV^t x\|$. Since $V^t$ preserves the norm, it is the same to minimize over the constraint $\|x\|=1$ and over the constraint $\|V^t x\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to be obtuse, I swear. I think I got most of it. But I'm still not sure why ||$x$|| = ||$V^Tx$||.

Comment: @lars: No need to apologize, a sincere question is a good question. Write $y=V^t x$. Since $VV^t=I$, multiplying termwise by $V$ one obtains $Vy =x$. Now $\|Vy\|=\|y\|$. This is the equation that we wanted, because the left hand side is $\|x\|$ and the right hand side is $\|V^t x\|$, and they are equal.